# visual studio Setup and Deployment Installation Folder

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The 'DefaultLocation' for my application is set to '[ProgramFilesFolder]\MyApp'. Now I would like the user to select what drive to install this application to. I know this is accomplished through the 'Installation Folder Selection' dialog, but I want the user to be able to select a drive only, not the entire path.

My question is how do I capture what drive the user selected from the 'Installation Folder Selection' dialog and use that drive letter to tack on to my 'DefaultLocation' variable?

Example: If the user selected "M:\" from the installation folder selection dialog, I want to install to "M:\Program Files\MyApp" or if the user selected "E:\", then install to "E:\Program Files\MyApp".......

Answer (score 1):

I never did that but I think its possible...

Select you setup project. Then, click the "User Interface" button in the toolbar of the Solution Explorer.
[image]

Then you should see the "User Interface" window (left on screenshot). You will see the "Installation Folder" dialog. Delete and add your own dialog by right-clicking on the "Start" node and selecting "Add Dialog".

No dialog exists that lets you select a drive. You may use the RadioButton and predefine 3 most common drive letters. I know this is not neat but its a workaround if you don't wan't to purchase a tool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
please tel me how to add the dropdown in the new dialog?

Comment: What dropdown? A drive dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

You can create setup projects with a project type in Visual Studio 2010 that's name is Setup/Deploy Project.

Or Visual Studio 2010 has a Install Shied Limited Edition project.

So you can use this and create more professional setups.

Comment: I know this process and have developed the setup with Setup/Deploy project. Now I just want that on the path selection screen during the setup the user can only select the drive not the complete path.